# How can I use my Blender models in WebGL

Tags: export, webgl

I would like to create WebGL applications and use Blender as a modelling tool. I don't necessarily need to translate game engine functionality to WebGL but I would like to retain as much of the UV mapping, vertex colors, materials, etc. info as possible.

I already know I should keep the polygon count low. What are the other things I should keep an eye on? (Such as `don't use feature X because you won't be able to export it`)

What tools do I need to learn? (WebGL framework specific plugins, generic tools like OBJ exporter)

Comment: [Blend4Web](http://www.blend4web.com) natively supports many Blender-specific features - node editor, NLA animation, particle system, Bullet physics and others

Comment: Page 414 in this book.
Its easy to use your Blender models in WebGL.
https://sites.google.com/site/webglbook/

Comment: Blend4Web development was abandoned in favor of Blend4Web Studio which won't be based on Blender anymore. Check out [Verge3D](https://www.soft8soft.com/) framework created by former B4W developers instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is somewhat dependent on what file format the WebGL viewer ingests. And how good the Blender exporter is. But the most common format is probably the ASCII Obj format, for which Blender has a pretty decent exporter for.

So, things to watch out for:

**Geometry**: Avoid Ngons, or at least, triangulate before exporting. The exporter might produce unexpected results. Also, make sure the face normals are all oriented correctly. Blender renders both side of a polygon by default, many other 3D viewers don't. You can recalculate normals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

**Mesh Modifiers**: Even though the exporter probably applies the modifiers. It's better to be explicit than implicit. Also, it is a good idea to apply the transforms (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).

**Materials and Textures:** Avoid the Blender material panel(except basic colors). Use UV-mapped textures. Blender-specific features like procedural textures are not going to migrate properly. Image textures dimensions should be power of 2 square. (`1024x1024`, `512x512`, etc)

Comment: All good points, You could also add that one should also remember to recalculate normals and make sure no duplicate verts are present.

Comment: On the WebGL side I'd recommend looking into [Three.js](http://threejs.org) It supports the Obj and other format and is very often used for all kinds of projects

Comment: Thanks, iKlsR, I added the bit about normals. Feel free to edit my answer next time.

Comment: +1 for apply modifiers. Also, don't forget to apply transforms.

Comment: Three.js comes with its own Blender import / export addon! https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender

Answer (score 10):

Blend4Web can do most of the work for you. It exports Blender models correctly and also sets up the WebGL page. It's free and open source.

https://www.blend4web.com/en/

June 2020 - blend4web does not appear to support the current version of Blender (v2.82)  It is not clear whether this product is even still available after it was reworked to support Maya and other environments,

Answer (score 4):

It seems you can now use the [Three.js Blender Exporter plugin](https://www.electronicarmory.com/articles/exporting-blender-models-to-threejs-webgl/) and export your model into a WebGL compatible JSON file and load it into your 3D scene using [Three.js](https://threejs.org/).