# How to export objects (.obj) and textures (.mtl) correctly?

Tags: export, image, texture-baking

Two questions :

1. How I can write my images textures at the same time as .obj and .mtl? The linked files are missing.
2. How I can write **the files paths correctly**.

I tested the file / external data but there isn't any changing.

Thank you for your replies

I try to make option copy, but it does not work, I do not understand.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/how-to-import-a-mtl-file https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly/24024#24024 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/408/how-can-i-use-my-blender-models-in-webgl/411#411 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7920/blender-isnt-importing-mtl-correctly-with-obj

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=obj%20textures

Comment: You could start by learning the basics and then think about exporting things for your game